# node js express twitter api login

Tags: node.js, express, pug, cloud9-ide

im a newbie with nodejs, actually i need to do a twitter login with the twitter API, i have been using this example http://moonlitscript.com/post.cfm/how-to-use-oauth-and-twitter-in-your-node-js-expressjs-app/ so, after spending some time trying to understand jade and all these new little things for me, i have managed to write something, however i have no idea of how i should send the info on my login page to the method that handles the twitter login process. Is there someone who can help me to point in the right direction with this? thanks in advance.

here's my code

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , OAuth= require('oauth').OAuth;

var app = express();

var oa = new OAuth(
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
"occcccccccc",
"fccccccccccccccccccccccccc",
"1.0",
"http://ccccccccccccc.c9.io/",
"HMAC-SHA1"
);

 app.get('/auth/twitter', function(req, res){
    oa.getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send("yeah no. didn't work.")
    }
    else {
        req.session.oauth = {};
        req.session.oauth.token = oauth_token;
        console.log('oauth.token: ' + req.session.oauth.token);
        req.session.oauth.token_secret = oauth_token_secret;
        console.log('oauth.token_secret: ' +    req.session.oauth.token_secret);
        res.redirect('https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate? oauth_token='+oauth_token)
}
});
});

app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', function(req, res, next){
if (req.session.oauth) {
    req.session.oauth.verifier = req.query.oauth_verifier;
    var oauth = req.session.oauth;

    oa.getOAuthAccessToken(oauth.token,oauth.token_secret,oauth.verifier, 
    function(error, oauth_access_token, oauth_access_token_secret, results){
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send("yeah something broke.");
        } else {
            req.session.oauth.access_token = oauth_access_token;
            req.session.oauth,access_token_secret =      oauth_access_token_secret;
            console.log(results);
            res.send("worked. nice one.");
        }
    }
    );
} else
    next(new Error("you're not supposed to be here."))
});



app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
})

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

//http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 //  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
 //});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + app.get('port'));
});
```

index.jade

```
   form(name="input", action="/auth/twitter", method="get")
  |Username:
  input(type="text", name="user")
  |Password:
  input(type="password", name="pswd")
  input(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

Comment: have you taken a look at this? [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth)

Comment: I know this is a long shot, but did you manage to figure it out? The information on it is still a little overwhelming.